# how to make ipa that cannot be installed on an iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I want to configure  iOS app that can be installed only in iPhone and apple watch not in iPad. For that I created the app for device type iPhone and generated the provisioning certificate for iPhone UDIDs only. Even tho I am able to install the app in iPad.

Am I missing some thing here ?

Comment: you can't do that, that does not make sense

Comment: there are tons of app  in app store that are only available for iPhone. How come this is valid.

Comment: No. There is no way to do that

Comment: As i remember iPad only apps can't be installed on iPhone, but iPhone only always can be installed on iPad

Comment: iPhones Apps are compatible for iPad by default. App will installed in iPad in compatibility mode.

Comment: iPhone apps run on an iPad at iPhone 4 resolution. You can’t prevent this when installing ad-hoc or via Xcode. If you are releasing the app to the store then requiring “telephony” in `UIDeviceCapabilities` will prevent your app being installed on an iPad.

Comment: Provisioning UDIDs for iPhone only should prevent app getting install in iPad in case of ADHoc Distribution right. But this also does not helped me.